# VIEW SQL data table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, pivot

**MY TABLE** name=maklumat

```
 |------------------|
 |DUN|JANTINA|JUMLAH|
  ------------------
 |A  |MELAYU |42    |
 |A  |CINA   |24    |
 |B  |CINA   |22    |
 |------------------|
```

I want to call `jantina` as my header table. The below table is what i want to view. Is it possible to view the below data just by using sql.

**NEEDED RESULT**

```
 |---------------|
 |DUN|MELAYU|CINA|
  ---------------
 |A  |42    |24  |
 |B  |0     |22  |
 |---------------|
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: Yes! which DBMS you are using? if sql-server then try to search for PIVOT.

Comment: i using phpmyadmin... it not oracle or postgres

Comment: Using Cross Tab Queries you can achieve this.

Comment: php admin means mySQL write? if yes, pivot is available in mySQL?

Comment: @AK47: pivot is not available in mysql

Comment: phpmyadmin is not a DBMS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this using CASE WHEN,

```
select  DUN
    ,SUM(Case When JANTINA = 'MELAYU' Then JUMLAH else 0 end) as MELAYU
    ,SUM(Case When JANTINA = 'CINA' Then JUMLAH else 0 end) as CINA
 from maklumat
 group by DUN
```

**[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8dbf4/1)**

Answer (score 1):

You can use [case](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html)

```
select DUN,
sum(case when jantina='MELAYU' then jumlah else 0 end) MELAYU,
sum(case when jantina='CINA' then jumlah else 0 end) CINA
from maklumat
group by DUN
```

[fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9319f2/5)